# How should I store the data with duplicated keys in a document for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, document, duplicates

I am now encountering a problem when storing some data into MongoDB.To be simple, its structure is illustrated  below:

```
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..4242774
                     /organism="Bacillus amyloliquefaciens subsp. plantarum YAU
                     B9601-Y2"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /strain="YAU B9601-Y2"
                     /sub_species="plantarum"
                     /db_xref="taxon:1155777"
     gene            412..1752
                     /gene="dnaA"
                     /locus_tag="BANAU_0001"
     CDS             412..1752
                     /gene="dnaA"
                     /locus_tag="BANAU_0001"
                     /function="ATPase involved in DNA replication initiation"
                     /codon_start=1
                     /transl_table=11
                     /product="Chromosomal replication initiator protein dnaA"
                     /protein_id="CCG48023.1"
                     /db_xref="GI:380496985"
                     /db_xref="GOA:H8XCH4"
                     /db_xref="UniProtKB/TrEMBL:H8XCH4"
                     /translation="MENILDLWNQALAQIEKKLSKPSFETWMKSTKAHSLQGDTLTIT
                     APNEFARDWLESRYLHLIADTIYELTGEELSVKFVIPQNQDEEDFLPKPQVKKAAKEE
                     PSDFPQSMLNPKYTFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPAKAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHL
                     MHAIGHYVIDHNPSAKVVYLSSEKFTNEFINSIRDNKAVDFRNRYRNVDVLLIDDIQF
                     LAGKEQTQEEFFHTFNTLHEESKQIVISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPP
                     DLETRIAILRKKAKAEGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLINKDIN
                     ADLAAEALKDIIPSSKPKVITIKEIQRIVGQQFNIKLEDFKAKKRTKSVAFPRQIAMY
                     LSREMTDSSLPKIGEEFGGRDHTTVIHAHEKISKLLIDDEQLQQQVKEIKELLK"
     gene            1937..3073
                     /gene="dnaN"
                     /locus_tag="BANAU_0002"
     CDS             1937..3073
                     /gene="dnaN"
```

From my illustration ,you can see that the key "gene" and "CDS" will be repeated for many times and from the MongoDB , I know that duplicated keys in a document is forbidden.So , my question is , how should I organize the data structure in mongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modeling duplicate fields at the same level in a document, you can use an array of subdocuments for the repeated elements like `genes` eg:

```
{
    source: "1..4242774",
    organism: "Bacillus amyloliquefaciens subsp. plantarum YAUB9601-Y2",
    mol_type: "genomic DNA",
    strain: "YAU B9601-Y2",
    sub_species: "plantarum",
    db_xref: "taxon:1155777",
    genes: [
        {
            id: '412..1752',
            gene: "dnaA",
        },
        {
            id: '1937..3073',
            gene: "dnaN",
        }
    ],
    CDS: [
        {
            id: '412..1752',
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information see [Array of Subdocuments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#array-of-subdocuments) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Yes ,I have already considered such an solution ,but ,it leads to another problem , what can I do if I want to query a set of genes whose id lies in a range? Should I load this gene array to my running program and complete the query all by myself?

Comment: Well,thank you very much.I have read the MongoDB document you supplied and get the answer.MongoDB have already supported this kind of query.Many thanks.